# How do I store all the values of a list of attribute values inside of one variable in R?

Tags: r, igraph

I have code like this:

```
library(igraph)
g <- make_empty_graph (2) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("a", value = 1) %>%
  add_vertices(2, color = 2, "a" = 2) %>%
  add_vertices(2, color = 4, "a" = 3) %>%
  add_edges(c(1,2, 2,1, 1,5, 5,1, 1,4 ,4,1)) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("xyz", value = 3)
plot(g)


i <- 1
prev_value <- FALSE

repeat {
  print(V(g)$a)
  print(mean(V(g)$a == 1))
  print(i)

  V(g)$xyz = sapply(V(g), function(x) {
    NeighborList = neighbors(g, x)
    length(NeighborList[NeighborList$a == 2])
  })
  V(g)$a[V(g)$xyz == 1] = 2
  prev_value <- V(g)$a[i]
  i <- i + 1


  if (V(g)$a[i] == prev_value) {
    break
  }

}
```

However, when I run this code, prev_value only stores the first value of V(g)$a. How would I fix this? When I run

```
print(prev_value)
```

The output I get is "1", whereas the output that I really want is '"1" "1" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0"' (initial value of V(g)$a)

Answer (score 0):

add indexing to prev_value so it builds up like a vector

```
i <- 1
prev_value <- FALSE

repeat {
  print(V(g)$a)
  print(mean(V(g)$a == 1))
  print(i)

  V(g)$xyz = sapply(V(g), function(x) {
    NeighborList = neighbors(g, x)
    length(NeighborList[NeighborList$a == 2])
  })

  if (V(g)$a[i] == prev_value[i-1]) {
    break
  }

  V(g)$a[V(g)$xyz == 1] = 2
  prev_value[i] <- V(g)$a[i]

  i <- i + 1
}
```

Comment: It returns "Error in if (V(g)$a[i] == prev_value[i - 1]) { : 
  argument is of length zero" and doesn't loop the commands